# Ionic 2 World Animation

Tags: javascript, cordova, animation, ionic2

I want to make an application with Ionic2 + Nodejs and want to add an animation of world that can be rotated and can be selected any country I heard Angular2 Animations but don't know if its able to do it. Is that possible or what else do I need to use?